# Why does my TypeScript give error TS2394?

Tags: typescript

I have a very simple function:

```
function open(callback) {

}
```

On the command line, when I run tsc, I get:

```
../../../../npm/lib/node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es6.d.ts(20833,18): error TS2394: Overload signature is not compatible with function implementation.
```

My tsc version is 2.6.1

Why am I getting the above error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why am I getting the above error message?

Your `tsconfig` is stuffed. Make sure you have setup `include` with some src folder e.g.

```
{
    "include":[
        "src"
    ]
}
```

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/compilation-context.html